# Issues performing a query to Solr via HttpClient using Solr 3.5 and HttpClient 4.2

Tags: apache, solr, httpclient, response

I am trying to query my local Solr server using HttpClient and I cannot figure out why the parameters are not being added to the `GET` call.

My code for doing this is:

```
HttpRequestBase request = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/solr/select");

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("q", query);
params.setParameter("start", String.valueOf(start));
params.setParameter("rows", String.valueOf(rows));

request.setParams(params);

HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream is = entity.getContent();

return stringToStreamConversion(is); //500 error, NullPointerException, response is empty
```

I have tried to return several things in hopes of seeing what I would get and trying to figure out where the problem was.  I have finally realized that I was only getting back the `http://localhost:8080/solr/select` when I returned

`return request.getURI().toURL().toString();`

I cannot figure out why the parameters are not getting added.  If I do

`return request.getQuery();`

I get nothing back...any ideas? Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I highly recommend using the Solrj library: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

Comment: I was using the Solrj library at first and was having issues trying to convert the SolrDocumentList to a json string, which is why I went with this approach

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen you are not able to associate your paeans with the request.

So, instead of creating a new HttpParams object and associating it with request, can you try the following approach ?

httpCclient.getParams().setParameter("q", query");
....

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work either.  I ended up constructing the URI from the URI constructor and decoding the query (because it had escaped characters).

Answer (score 0):

The simpler option is to use the approach I used in [HTTPPostScheduler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#HTTPPostScheduler), like this:

```
URL url = new URL(completeUrl);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("type", "submit");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

// Send HTTP POST
conn.connect();
```